# Why can't Xshell be used and hint "To continue using this program, you must apply the latest update or use a new version"

Tags: xshell

I don't konw why Xshell could't use and commit "To continue using this program, you must apply the latest update or use a new version"
I'm trying to open nslicense.dll with C32ASM to change it that I heard from Internet .Bud It does't work.So do the XFtp[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGWE1.png)
XShell is Free For Home And School

Comment: Pic may be cat't be see .That'Ok .Just a prompt.

Comment: And it also hint "You need to update your Xshell ".But It ' do up to date!

Comment: It'goes Ok  when I uninstall and download a new Xshell!